# Prevent insert in Database based on current value

Tags: java, sql-server-2005

I am developing a system for booking or reservation. In my form, i make a ajax call to check if there is space available and disable them if they are full. Unfortunately there are instances when there is 1 space available and 10 try to submit the response, it exceeds the allocated space by 1 or 2.

I do not expect any code or query but guidelines how this can be prevented?

Comment: How is designed your database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve reliable synchronization with client technologies, you will have to dig deeper in the stack.
You should defer this check at a later stage, and handle it at server side (in java, c#, etc) or in a stored procedure.
Use your javascript for a preliminary check: if there is no space available, disable the form immediately. However, if there is space available, the form will look enabled BUT it might fail later, in your java code or your stored procedure. That stage should be synchronized, and if you detect that there is no space because you just served a customer, return an error message to the rest, even though they had seen an enabled form.

Comment: I have a check during onload() to disable buttons, then another ajax call when user clicks a radio button. I have not used stored procedure but use batch sql in java to upload information. Thats when i experience that even after these checks i have a situation when the number exceeds the capacity by 1 to 3.

Comment: The important thing is to understand why these checks are not enough. Have a look at what a transaction is. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction I don't know what sql batch is, but it will be very handy enclosing your business logic in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the "is there a space available / reserve a space" in a mutex transaction, so that at most one client can check/reserve a space.  Yes, many requests will wait, but if the critical section is small, the wait time will be negligible overall.

Answer (score 0):

I would like locking part to be done in DB.
Read through many isolation levels provided by transaction Something like repeatable read for this particular section should solve the problem.
Aim to ensure DB to acquire locks even for read operations.
You can write a stored proc for this or you can even do it in Application layer.
And don't forget to reset the transaction level after you are done.